# Center bars of histogram using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to center my bars with the ggplot2 package. The bars are not aligned to the center of the corresponding value, which can lead to some misunderstanding for non-expert readers. My plot looks like this:

[image]

In order to reproduce the plot, please use the following code:

```
# Load data
Temp <- read.csv("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=mpFpjqJt", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep = ";")
# Load package
library(ggplot2)
# Plot histogram using ggplot2
ggplot(data=Temp, aes(Temp$Score)) + 
geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0, 8, by =1), col="grey", aes(fill=..count..), binwidth = 1, origin = -0.5) 
+ scale_fill_gradient("Count", low = "green", high = "red") 
+ labs(title="Title") 
+ labs(x="X-Title", y="Y-Title") 
+ xlim(c(3,9))
```

How I can center each bar to the corresponding x-value?

**Edit 2017-05-29**
As the download link may break in the future, here are the data as returned by `dput()`

```
Temp <- structure(list(ID = 1:30, Score = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L)), .Names = c("ID", "Score"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

Comment: is your Score numeric?

Comment: Yepp, it is. The Score-values are only numbers as you can see here: http://pastebin.com/mpFpjqJt

Comment: without the data it's hard to test but try ggplot(data=Temp, aes(as.factor(Score)))...

Comment: if Score can only take few values and you want a bar per value, maybe a barplot would be better suited than a histogram ?

Comment: @CathG: You're right. The range is only between 1 and 7, so a bar plot could also be a suitable approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove the `breaks` argument, which is redundant / in conflict with the `binwidth` and `origin` arguments:

```
# Load data
Temp <- read.csv("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=mpFpjqJt", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep = ";")
# Load package
library(ggplot2)
# Plot histrogram using ggplo2
ggplot(data=Temp, aes(Temp$Score)) + 
  geom_histogram(col="grey", aes(fill=..count..), binwidth = 1, origin = -0.5) + 
  scale_fill_gradient("Count", low = "green", high = "red") + 
  labs(title="Title") + 
  labs(x="X-Title", y="Y-Title") + 
  xlim(c(3,9))
```

Comment: That's great -Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: in **ggplot2** (v3.3.3) instead of  `origin` either `center` or `boundary` can be used (as the other answer says).

Answer (score 7):

[Michael Kuhn's answer of Dec 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34180398/3817004) is returning a warning nowadays:

> `origin` is deprecated. Please use `boundary` instead.

According to [the release notes of version 2.1.0 of `ggplot2`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/releases/ggplot2-2.1.0.html):

> You can now specify either boundary (i.e. the position of the left or right side) or the center of a bin. origin has been deprecated in favour of these arguments.

So with `ggplot2`version 2.1.0 and above, the suggested way forward is to use **either** the `boundary` parameter:

```
library(ggplot2)   # CRAN version 2.2.1 used
ggplot(data=Temp, aes(Score, fill = ..count..)) + 
  geom_histogram(col = "grey", binwidth = 1, boundary = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_gradient("Count", low = "green", high = "red") +
  labs(title = "Title") +
  labs(x = "X-Title", y = "Y-Title") +
  xlim(c(3, 9))
```

**or** the `center` parameter

```
...
geom_histogram(col = "grey", binwidth = 1, center = 0) +
...
```

The result is the same:

[image]

BTW: I have removed a minor flaw in OP's code which was using `Temp$Score` in the `aes()` call `ggplot(data=Temp, aes(Temp$Score))` instead of `ggplot(data = Temp, aes(Score))`.

#### Data

As the download link may break in the future, here are the data as returned by `dput()`:

```
Temp <- structure(list(ID = 1:30, Score = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L)), .Names = c("ID", "Score"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```